# addeventlistener for multiple textbox with same id and class name

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have problem in executing addeventlistener can anyone help me this is my code..

```
function gettext(){
     var val=this.value; 
    console.log(val);
} 
var get=document.getElementById('ids'); 
for(i=0; i<get.length;i++){
     console.log(i);
     document.getElementById(get[i]).addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
}
```

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Comment: this is what am using <form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test1">
  <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test2">
</form>

Comment: Give them different id's - getElementById will always only return one element - the first one found. Or try using document.querySelectorAll('[id="ids"]'); instead

Comment: what i am exactly trying is i have 5 textbox, when i click the first text box it should pop up some text related to first textbox and so on how can i do this. any suggestions. As it is in gmail signup page

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jDBx/

As Prabha Karan said, ids are supposed to be unique. Use classes instead.

```
function gettext() {
    var val = this.value;
    console.log(val);
}
var get = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');
for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    get[i].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
}
```

If you want, you can define multiple classes for one element. Simply use `<input type="text" id="id1" class="test1 secondClassName thirdClassName" value="test1">`